# About Vidalia not working/discontinued

Tags: vidalia, linux

If I try to install Vidalia on Ubuntu it does not work. It returns an error about user/permission on `/var/run/tor` directory `... maybe you are running tor with the wrong user`

- Why has the Vidalia project been discontinued ?
- Is there any alternative that offer the same functionality ?
- Is there any way to use Vidalia ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vidalia has been discontinued for a long time now because it has not been maintained to keep up with changes in tor. At present there is no officially recommended alternative, though I have heard some rumors about it being revived.

To answer "Is there any way to use it?" Yes of course it is possible, but you should not use it. It is discontinued for a reason, and we don't know the security implications of using unmaintained software.

As a side note, you make it sound like you are using packages out of the Ubuntu repositories. See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en for a warning telling you to not using Ubuntu's repositories for tor.

Comment: "At present there is no officially recommended alternative" What about [Arm](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en)? It's advertised as a "`top`-like utility for Tor" but also allows configuration and basic status checks like Vidalia.